# Find all 2 x 2 skew-symmetric matrices A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find all $2 \times 2$ skew-symmetric matrices $A$, if any, such that $A^2 + I_2 = 0$

Please help me! Thanks!!

Comment: you tried something?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Caffeine deficit. I am linearly dependent on my tea.

Comment: @copper.hat:  you need to hit up that infamous caffiene trafficker, the Caffe Med, for a fix!  And an enjoyable Turkey Day to thee and thine!

Comment: @RobertLewis: Yes indeed! Happy Turkey day to you too!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Every $2\times 2$ skew-symmetric matrix has the form $\begin{pmatrix}0&t\\-t&0\end{pmatrix}$, so all you need to do is find those $t$ that have the desired property. Writing out the elements of $A^2+I$ explicitly would lead you a long way.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $A^2 + I_2 = 0$, then what are the eigenvalues of $A$?  $A$ will be a satisfactory matrix if and only if it has the correct eigenvalues and is unitarily similar to a diagonal matrix.